# iphone base sdk and FBConnect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fbconnect

I have noticed that when i set base sdk to 3.2 even when i run the app on a 4.+ ios device every time you switch between apps ,the app restarts .When bask sdk is 4.+ resumes from where it was left.
The issue i'm facing is with the new fbconnect which uses app switching for the authentication.If the base sdk is 3.2 ,it switches to either the FB app or safari and then restarts my app and i dont seem to get the url that it passes so i can register the authentication.With a 4.+ base as i said the app resumes correctly and authenticates.
I guess i'm messing something here.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states that:

> Single sign-on is available for apps
>   built on version of iOS that support
>   multitasking (generall v4.0 and
>   higher--see Apple documentation for
>   more information). Others applications
>   will fall back to inline dialog-based
>   authorization.

And in any case, you should always be using the latest SDK (which, as of Xcode 3.2.5 you can finally specify just as "Latest iOS" rather than having to update your projects every time a new SDK comes out) and setting the iOS Deployment Target lower if you want to support earlier versions of the OS.

The DemoApp that comes with the latest FB Connect has the base SDK set to latest and the deployment target set to iOS 3.0. As a test, I built that and installed it onto a 3.1.3 device. Upon clicking the 'login' button on the first screen the old fashioned login box appeared directly in my app. I installed the same app onto a 4.2.1 device and the login button instead took me to the browser.

So I'm not sure exactly what's going on in your project, but you should probably set the base SDK and deployment target correctly, then compare to the supplied DemoApp if things still seem not to be working.

Comment: Ok thanks,did change the deployment target and setting the base to latest.I was missing the deployment target.